# Garbage Collection During Simple Allocations

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

So I was tracking down what I thought was excessive GC during some of my code. I eventually boiled it down to this code that showed what I was seeing:

```
object[] ret = new object[40000000];
for (int i = 0; i < 40000000; i++)
{
    ret[i] = new object();
}
```

While running that loop, I was seeing dozens of Garbage Collection Gen1 events. Does anyone have a good understanding of why this is? What no-longer-referenced objects is it cleaning up while filling this array?

Here's a picture as more reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPQ91.jpg

I wouldn't expect any GC to be happening until I lost reference to an object I created. Maybe I'm being braindead today or there's some fundamental concept I'm missing, but it seemed curious to me.

Thanks!

Comment: you are allocating way too much ram that it forces GC to run under pressure.

Comment: Okay, so allocation pressure forces GC to run?  Is there a way to help avoid this during times of heavy allocation?

Comment: It sees the memory usage is super high so it tries to see if it can find anything that could be freed up to reduce memory footage.

Comment: question: *why* are you allocating 40M objects? there's almost certainly something very wrong with your approach here; now, we can help answer the immediate question, but I'd also love to help fix the bigger *what you're actually doing* issue; 40M different object references in an array is getting [well into assault by GC territory](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2011/10/assault-by-gc.html)

Comment: Well, this is just a simplistic generic example.  The code that inspired the post is reading in 300 megabytes of data into classes in memory.  It doesn't necessarily run slow, but in seeing if there was any places to speed it up, I noticed the heavy GC (30% time spent) in a period where I expected only objects to be created, which was confusing initially.  Makes more sense now after having read these answers

Comment: @Leviathan1753 I wonder whether `struct` (preferably `readonly struct`) would be your friend here; an array of a few million structs is : one object. More importantly, there aren't 40M object references to crawl each and every GC. Take a look at the blog post I linked to - it might really help you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because it ran a gen1 doesn't mean it *collected* anything - it means it *tried* (precisely because you had allocated lots of objects!). It doesn't know, until it tries, whether it will succeed.

> I wouldn't expect any GC to be happening until I lost reference to an object I created.

Nope; GC *collects* object that aren't reachable, but it *runs* whenever it feels is appropriate (for example, based on allocations - or due to external memory pressure from the OS).

Comment: Awesome.  That makes a lot more sense.  It needs more memory, and it's just checking around for spare room before making more.

Is there any way to oil this during a time of known heavy allocations?  Or is that just how memory managed languages go?

Comment: @Leviathan1753 again, the first thing I'd want to look at here is whether this should actually be an array of `struct` values, not classes